# Android: Speech Recognition without using google server

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline

I want to develop an Speech recognizer in android, which should work in offline. As the android's built-in speech recognizer uses google server which needs internet, i want an alternative which works in the absence of internet.

Please suggest me some way to achieve the above feature.

Comment: Please use SO as per the regulations. This is a very clean place, please help to keep it that way.

Comment: Has Google made this easy using SpeechRecognizer?  http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/15/utter-claims-to-be-the-first-non-ime-app-to-utilize-offline-voice-recognition-in-jelly-bean/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388720/cant-start-service-speech-recog

Answer (score 54, accepted):

We used to recommend pocketsphinx, but now more advanced technology based on Kaldi toolkit is available.

The demo is here: [Vosk API](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-android-demo/), you can simply load it in Android Studio and run. Full disclosure: I am the primary author of Vosk.

It supports speech recognition in 7 major languages - English, Chinese, Spanish, Portuguese, German, French and Russian.

Comment: @Swathi EP did you have any success?

Comment: Yes, he did. See this thread http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/5471/topic/4022625

Comment: Hi Tom, You want to know the steps to run android pocketsphinx demo project refer: http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html

Comment: Why it is closed as not a real question by Kev♦ ?? This is not only a real question, it's a research problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the speech recognizer has limited vocabulary (as in a simple voice user interface)  and is limited few samples - it maybe possible. Applications such as Transcription is not a likely task to be performed on Android (in offline mode). Also DSP is required for Voice Recognition ... A limited vocabulary and limited to very few samples might be your best bet.

Comment: yes, i need only limited vocabulary. My requirement is to have voice commands to trigger applications.

Comment: I'd recommend seeing if you can figure out (academic papers maybe?) how "dumbphones" do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to invest time and manpower for your goal, look at the Java-Project Java Speech API 2.0 (JSR 113).

It is used on "normal" mobile phones for voice commands and works offline.
Unfortunately, the project is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Google voices for later use.
From you mobile -> Setting -> “Language and Input” ->  "Voice Search" ->  "Download offline speech recognition" -> Choose the language pack .

Or you can use other programs, such as 
Dragon Mobile Assistant
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.balerion&hl=en

Comment: Seems to be incompatible with nexus 5? What about http://www.nuancemobilelife.com/apps/ ?

Comment: And there is no "Download offline speech recognition" on my kit kat

Comment: There is no "Download offline speech recognition" on my Jelly Bean (4.1.2) either. Nexus S. Looks like a whimsical feature.

Comment: http://www.kizeo.com/how-to-enable-offline-speech-recognition-on-samsungandroid-devices/

But you can find it in slightly different places depending on your exact version.  It's available even on MIUI V5

Comment: @skan Thank you. I did arrive at the same exact screen shown in the link you provided but instead of the 3 options ("Choose input languages", "Block offensive words" and "Offline speech recognition"), I only have 2 options on my phone (**No** "Offline speech recognition"). Weird.

Comment: Maybe depends on your firmware. I'm sorry I can't help you more. Perhaps you can download it in some other way.

Comment: Only one android version, which I don't remember, was blessed with this feature.

Answer (score -3):

You're not going to be happy with this workaround but here goes: Record the speech & store it for later.  When an internet connection is available, connect to the internet, playback the recorded speech and convert it to text.

Hey, it's the easiest way I can think of and might work for some applications, like dictation and memos.

Comment: So "offline" means "connect to the internet later"?!?!?