# Voice Recognition for Galaxy Tab - Offline

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Is there any Voice recognition service that works in an offline mode (without intenet connectivity) for Samsung Galaxt tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

[Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server/)

It's basically the same question

Comment: But the project doesnot work. I get missing import files error.

Comment: You are welcome to post your problems on the forum. I'm sure you'll get help to make it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Android voice recognition requires Internet connectivity. The recognition is not performed on the device, but rather uses Google web services. So, you must be online. Some info on the web services is available at http://waxy.org/2008/11/deconstructing_google_mobiles_voice_search_on_the_iphone/.

Comment: Yes but it is using google service... i want something that doesnot use google service

Comment: You've got to build your own. Nikolay's answer links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server/ which should be helpful.