# Pronunciation recognition - speech API or algorithm

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, speech-recognition

Is there any API for Windows Phone - or some other method besides sending audio to a server - to recognize how correctly a particular word is pronounced?

What I'm *not* looking for is to recognize it semantically or against any other criteria than a source audio file for comparison (with something like a confidence level for how accurately a user says a particular word compared to the source audio file).

I've looked around quite a bit and haven't been able to find anything that could be run solely on a Windows Phone without a connection to a server.

If no API exists, is there a .NET set of classes (open source) that could be modified for use to this end?

Comment: How many words are we talking about here (including correct word and all incorrect combinations)? And how many languages? The size of the database for your application will be critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PocketSphinx` runs on Android. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server/4396749#4396749)). I am not sure if you would have a port for Windows phone. The models etc. you might use are free to be shipped. I think that with `Pocketsphinx`, you can also ship code.

Comment: And Pocketsphinx will require you to do some custom development to implement pronunciation evaluation, see for details http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qhow_to_implement_pronunciation_evaluation

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev: both of those links under "Pronunciation Evaluation" are 404 dead links. Do you know of updated links to those articles?

Comment: @Stan. Sorry, it become outdated. I've updated the wiki text, now you should have a link.

Comment: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/pocketsphinx_pronunciation_evaluation/

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen one out there for what your asking for, but that doesn't mean you should give up. I strongly encourage you to build one yourself if you don't find one.

Also i think an easy way out would be to just use the library's for voice, but that will call out of the application.
Maybe try contacting their Dev Support for the windows phone and see if you can get data files just on that language you want and then allow it to be embedded into the application.

I hope that helps!