# Audio fingerprinting in android

Tags: android, arduino, audio-fingerprinting

I am working on an android project for controlling an arduino robot using speech recognition. i wanted an offline speech recognition unit to recognise only a few words. so thought of implementing audio fingerprinting for the purpose. so is there anyway i can use ths to recognise a few simple words.???

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/

Comment: you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server/4396749#4396749 as a offline api

Answer (score 0):

What you need to implement is more related to audio recognition/classification. You will not get what you want using audio fingerprinting.

Lets say you have 5 words, you need to record these words (as many times as possible and pronounced by different people if possible). Then you need to extract audio features (such as MFCC) from these recordings and to train a classifier (such as a SVM) with 5 classes (one for each word).