# Convert speech to text in android without internet and google server

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I have a list of english words. I want search with voice. When I say word display list of words. I read [Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server?rq=1)
. 
And I tried some examples.

```
package com.uz.VoiceRecognizw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private ListView wordsList;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);

        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

        wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Disable button if no recognition service is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() == 0)
        {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }
    public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
    {
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches));
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This example work with internet.
I want search words without internet and google server. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sardor, there is no way to satisfy your demand directly. Through your description, you are looking for Offline-ASR that has a extra resource which contains the list of english words to do this. Some Voice firms support Offline-ASR, you can try to contact them to  customize resource. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pocket sphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

But you have to be familiar with speech recognition field and build the acoustic model yourself. You can use free voice corpus from http://voxforge.org to build acoustic model or you can find already built acoustic models from Internet

Comment: Everything is correct except that the models from CMUSphinx distribution are way better than voxforge models. You can find latest models here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android JellyBean (or higher) then you can download language packs and use them for offline speech recognition.

Go to : Settings->Language and Input->Voice Search->Offline Speech Recognition. Download the language pack you want to use.