# Adding continuous speech recognition to my Android app

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to add a voice interface to my Android app.  Two requirements:

- I only need to recognize from a small dictionary of words at any time - basically any clickable element on screen, and most of the clickable elements already have text on them, so it would literally be "say what you see".
- Continuous voice recognition while the app is visible, although I could live with having to say "Ok app" before the speech to be acted upon.

What is the optimum way to implement this?

Thanks
NickB

Comment: Check [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it has all that implemented

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something offline, I'd look at PocketSphinx (https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/).  I used it for offline wake word recognition.  It seems to err on the side of being more accepting of what you say, rather than less.

For continuous listening, you might look at IBM's Watson's Speech to Text software (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk), which is a cloud bases Speech to Text.

I was able to combine the two, using PocketSphinx to detect wake words and then using Watson to get good speech to text results.