# Is any api for android who converts voice into text (Offline)

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I know the way how converts voice into text using recognition intent of google in android i did that thing but i want direct recognition from my application is any way to do that

Comment: what you are asking elaborate. Intent of google in android can also work offline.

Answer (score 1):

Pocketsphinx can run on Android.

[CMU Sphinx (at SourceForge)](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)

you can get full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server/4396749#4396749).