# no more offline speech recognition?

Tags: android

Today I noticed that offline speech recognition doesn't work anymore.
It worked before because I was able to use it for my app and I'm completely sure that I was offline and everything was working fine then.
I wanted to test my app today and it couldn't understand what I said no matter how loud I said it.

Then I turned the wifi on and it was working perfectly. I'm using the same phone though, sony xperia L, same OS, Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2. I have no idea what happened. Has Google changed something or what? And it's not just my app, other apps that need speech recognition won't work offline as well. Can someone explain this and tell me if there something I can do to get offline speech recognition again, or at least make it work for my app?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: i've tested it on xperia z2 now and it has the same problem, so it's not only my phone, i believe there was an update with some bugs from google, what do you think?
is it going to be fixed or do i have to fix it?
i want my app to work offline

EDIT 2: i solved my problem by uninstalling all updates on Google App and getting back its factory version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)

Comment: not really, my question is different, and that question is old (2013), offline mode was working fine for me then stopped working all of a sudden

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server as well.

Comment: i solved my problem by uninstalling all updates on Google App and getting back its factory version.

Comment: I also have the same problem with the most recent version of the Google app.