# Speech recognition offline mode does not work in my app but works in other apps

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I'm developing an application that use Google speech recognition , i'm installing English packages for US and UK , but when i run my app i can't use the offline feature , but in Other apps like Google Chrome it's works like a charm for offline mode , i don't know what i missed , is it the configuration or something in my code .

THis is my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en_UK");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "speach not supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and this is a capture from my app it always says Touch the mic Try speaking again

[image]

Comment: Do you know apps besides Google apps that work that way? It is not uncommon that Google's own apps have features that are not generally available.

Comment: It was working before that , i don't know how , but know something happens and offline mode does not working anymore . 
and i did not get what do you mean .

Answer (score 1):

I've been having exactly the same issue and i just found that is some bug with an Google App update's, so you have to go to settings > apps > Google > remove updates and then download your language packages again and that's all

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582110/no-more-offline-speech-recognition)