# is it possible to make a voice recognizing android app which don't uses internet?

Tags: android, api, voice-recognition

I know that android already have an own recognizing voice API but it uses internet, I would like to have like a compiled library with a few voice commands that I could use offline, is that possible?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server) will probably be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you would have to train a model to convert speech to commands.
A simple approach could be to break speech at intervals where the amplitude is minimum, this will give you the words in the speech, match these words with your model with some probability if the matched probability is higher than some threshold value your model can then help execute the commands related to that word. You will have to ship this model within your application. i would recommend to update the model as you train your model further.