# Speech Recognition without Google services For Epson GLass AR App

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, epson

Voice recognition is supported in android devices but i want to build an Ar App for Epson Glass which does not support Google Services so the Voice Recognizer of the Google API is not working.
As there any SdK or library which provide facility of speech to Text Functionality.
I have search a lot on the internet but none of the solution have solve my problem there are solutions available for offline mode speech recognition while using google services and i want speech recognition facility for devices which does not support the google services which is the major problem. i have applied all the solution there but none of them work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev brother the question you have given does not related to my question the question there was only for offline mode while using google services and i want to this work without google services which are very different because i have applied all the solution there but none of them work for me.thanks

Answer (score 0):

IBM, Amazon, and Microsoft all have speech recognition APIs that should work fine on BT-300. I have not tested any of them, but there's no reason they shouldn't work.

Note that BT-300 has Android version 5.0.5, so you might check OS requirements before doing any work, but I would expect those three to all work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which model of Moverio are you using, but **in case it's the BT-2000/2200**, you can find some **samples** and references here:

**https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-2000/sdk_download.html**

It will download a .zip file, with the SDK and the samples.
If you go trough **BT2000_SDK_SampleProject.zip** you will see a project named **SampleVoiceCommand**.

Then you'll see how Moverio works with the speech recognition. Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i know that BT-2000 have built in voice recognition features but i want for bt-200 and bt-300