# Does the Google Assistant SDK function offline?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Can I build custom actions to leverage the Google Assistant SDK without needing to be online?  I'd like to have the natural language parser to help me navigate my Android App, even when offline.  That is, speak to it and say special words to navigate the screens and what not, using the voice instructions of the user.

This seems totally possible using the Assistant SDK on the internet, but I need the app to run on my android even outside of connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Google assistant uses google servers so I don't think it is possible, but there are some other options check out this link. 
[Android: Speech Recognition without using google server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396046/android-speech-recognition-without-using-google-server)