# Android Continuous Speech recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, continuous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous Speechrecognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027466/continious-speechrecognition-in-android)

I understand the current speech recognition method where you can have the user click a button to recognize a phrase. But does anyone know if continuous speech recognition is possible? For example, using voice commands control the phone (without clicking a button) to launch apps or provide an interactive information to the visually impaired or someone driving a car.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027466/continious-speechrecognition-in-android
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148603/continuous-speech-recognition-android