# Voice recognition in android app that is always listening

Tags: android, android-intent, voice-recognition

I'm trying to add some voice recognition to my app that is always listening (like a service).  I want it to perform different actions when it recognizes certain spoken words ie: "total time", "maximum speed" etc would then fire off an event that does something in my app.

So far I've only been able to find adding the voice recognition to an activity.  I *could* sit that activity over the top of my app's activity, but I'd rather not do that.  Also, I'm not sure if it would *always* be listening which I want.  I don't want to have to press a button to fire off the voice recognition listener.  I want to be able to keep my phone in my pocket and speak through my microphone on my headset and just have it do what I tell it.  I'd be ok with having to say something like "Ok Google" to have it start listening for commands, but if it's already listening for that, can't I just have it listen for the app's commands?

Comment: It always amuses me when people ask questions and say "this is an emergency"....makes me think they're in school and have to have a program done for an assignment and want others to do it for them.  This is not an emergency.  Whenever you can answer, is fine.  Thx.

Comment: You can try CMUSphinx android demo: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid. It can continuously listen for one or many commands, commands are configurable.

Comment: And, this question has been asked many times before, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148603/continuous-speech-recognition-android

Comment: Recent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321893/voice-command-keyword-listener-in-android/24322532#24322532