# Android voice activation to perform action in application

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am looking to add voice activation to my Android project.  I would like that when audio is detected via the smartphone mic or earpiece attached it triggers an action on my app and stops when no audio is detected.  And also have ease of threshold control.  I've seen a few options like speex and other with links that are no longer working or projects have dead. But was wondering if there is any other good options on how to implement on Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice command keyword listener in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321893/voice-command-keyword-listener-in-android)