# How can I implement a Voice Recognition android app without Google Speech API?

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recognition

I'm thinking about work on a Voice Screen Locker/Unlocker Android App as my Final Graduation Project and I'm having some problems on how Can I turn on the microphone when a press the Lock Button so it can keep listening until the Password  is spoken.

Is the same idea of the "Ok Google" feature, but with a personalized password and I can't use the Google Speech API.

I have to capture the password, process and unlock(or not) the screen if the password is right.

I've searched about it, but I only find techniques using RecognizerIntent and other classes of Google Speech API.

I need to know how can I start to listen the mic when lockscreen is displayed so can i capture the audio stream. Isn't allowed to me use any api no Google Speech neither Pocketsphinx
Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice command keyword listener in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321893/voice-command-keyword-listener-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use other APIs like Pocketsphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid