# react-native - Listen for specific word?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, microphone, speech-to-text

I am building a cross-platform (iOS, Android) app using React-Native. On one of my Scenes, I want the device to listen in the background for a specific word (say "Next"), and on hearing that word, trigger an event.

I already searched for different speech-to-text APIs, and I might find one fairly easy (Wit.ai seems pretty good, even though it might be a bit overkill).

The problem resides in the fact of letting the microphone listen in background, and firing an event when a word is said, and not when there is background noise.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice command keyword listener in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321893/voice-command-keyword-listener-in-android)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/pylon/react-native-spokestack