# How do you leave the microphone on in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, microphone, speech-to-text

I am currently doing a speech to text project. The person in question could be talking randomly and for random lengths of time. On various phrases the app responds according to the phrase. At the moment the user has to press a button to begin the recording. So far I have no issues with doing speech to text and grabbing key phrases from the snippet. But having to continually press the button is not an option. So where should I be looking as to pressing a start and stop button and have the microphone stay on?

This of course leads to other questions and issues. I'm not looking for answers to the following things, but I will state them so that you can see what I have considered.

Will the mobile device overheat with the mic staying on?
How do you leave the mic on while converting 2 seconds of speech to text every 2 seconds
I did instantiate 2 instances of turning on the mic which overlapped each other... I can tell you the device did not like this at all

Thanks for any hints and suggestions
I am sure there will be other issues I've not thought of.
I am using a pc and the latest version of Android Studio. 1.4 I believe it is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous Speech Recognition Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148603/continuous-speech-recognition-android)

Comment: Most of the approaches are explained in other question. Continuous large vocabulary speech recognition will drain battery for sure, you need lightweight keyword spotting. You can not open microphone twice, you need to properly implement listening on the background.