# Android Continuous Speech Recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech, android-speech-api

I'm working on an application that would require continuous speech recognition. The app will listen for only a few defined keywords, but once the listener gathers the users voice input, it will need to keep listening for more keywords until the user stops the listener.

The best solution I've found is the Nuance speech recognition library, but this isn't perfect and it could get very expensive. Has anyone else been able to get this type of functionality working?

---

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow! To answer your question - yes! Now, take your time and please read how things work on this site: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's a lot of friendly people here, who are willing to help you, you just need to show some effort first :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous Speech Recognition Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148603/continuous-speech-recognition-android)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev is there a way for an Android application to use CMUSphinx to give the user continuous offline speech recognition. I have tried this as well but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You can listen for activation keyword continuously, large vocabulary is not possible.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev how is this possible to keep listening a single keyword for Long time I mean until the particular Screen is not destroyed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Oxford API of Mircosoft](https://www.projectoxford.ai/speech)

This can give you continuous real time speech recognition, and then you can look for special keywords. Maybe it's an overkill in your case so be sure to check more options !

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this library a try and will let you know how it works out for me.

Comment: I pulled down the project from GitHub (http://tinyurl.com/hz8uxa2) and it worked. It allowed for long gaps of no speech which is what I was looking for. Thank you for your input!